# No hover performed after upgrade to Selenium 4.8.3

Tags: java, maven, selenium4

After upgrade of Selenium from 3 to 4, the hover is not anymore performed in the following method:

```
public void mouseMoveToRightEdge(Element element) {
        executeAction(element, new EventType(EventType.Message.ACTION_HOVER), (by, failedEx) -> {
            WebElement webElement = driverServices.getDriver().findElement(by);
            Dimension d = webElement.getSize();

            int xOffset = d.width - 2; //Works on remote running (maven/selenoid) only when reducing 2 pixels
            int yOffset = d.height / 2;

            org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions builder = new org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions(driverServices.getDriver());
            org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions hoverOverRightEdge = builder.moveToElement(webElement, xOffset, yOffset);
            hoverOverRightEdge.perform();
            return true;
        });
    }
```

Is there any better way in Selenium 4 to perform the hover to certain offsets? Are the offsets seen different in Selenium 4?

I tried to change the offsets to other values from the element and it didn't work. I tried to use clickAndHold method insetead moveToElement and it wasn't working either.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was about the zoom of the element and this is a known problem, that if the zoom is different than 100%, the method `moveToElement` might not work as expected. More details [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=628)